# How can I stop ubuntuone-syncd?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, services

I need to stop ubuntuone-syncd but I don't know where to find the service that I need to stop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu One comes with the commandline tool `u1sdtool` to control it.

Basically the gui control panel cannot quit the syncdaemon but can connect/disconnect it.

If you need to control syncdaemon start/stop it

you have `u1sdtool --start` and `u1sdtool --quit`

If you need to connect/disconnect it

you have `u1sdtool --connect` and `u1sdtool --disconnect` commands

See `u1sdtool --help` for all the available commands.

You can do connect/disconnect through control panel gui as well.

There is a indicator for ubuntuone as well: [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/38054#38054)

If you need to disable ubuntuone from autostarting at login 
Syncdaemon is autostart service. So if you just need to disable the autostart part when you login to your session. Go to `/etc/xdg/autostart` and do

`sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' ubuntuone-launch.desktop`

and disable it from `startup-applications`

Comment: amazing! yes, disable ubuntuone from the start, for the moment, is my goal. thanks!

Comment: You do not want to edit the file in /etc/xdg/autostart directly. You should instead copy it into your ~/.config/autostart/ directory, and change the X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled key to false to disable autostart.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this works, but you can stop (and start) the client by using the commandos

`u1sdtool --quit`

`u1sdtool --start`

soure: [Subfolders not syncing in Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82587/subfolders-not-syncing-in-ubuntu-one)

Comment: ok. right. u1sdtool --quit stopping ubuntuone-syncdaemon

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is is started via dbus daemon. 
`apt-get remove ubuntuone-client` will uninstall it.
Or you could rename `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.service` and restart dbus, that might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, first list all services to ensure you call stop on the correct one:

```
service --status-all
```

then (still in the terminal)

```
service [insert name] stop
```

and to restart:

```
service [insert name] start
```

NB: the square brackets are not part of the command and should be removed :-)

Comment: Ok. Is not a service but a dbus deamon.