# Stop Ubuntuone from autostart

Tags: ubuntu-one, startup, services

I want to stop ubuntuone from autostart.

I have already tried the suggestions from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123678/how-can-i-do-to-stop-ubuntuone-syncd)
but it didn't help me.
My current status is that I have deleted the ubuntuone-launch.desktop file from `/etc/xdg/autostart` but the service still start's at log-in.

Any suggestions before purging it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Boot Up Manager

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

and disable the service from Boot Up Manager.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please click on the grey tick mark to mark it solved.

Comment: I have only checked the outcome today. After bum, I did not see Ubuntu-One there (I did stop some other services though, from boinc) now I don't have Ubuntu one started. So I am not sure what happened...but U1 is no longer auto-started, and that's what I was aiming at. Thx all!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One starts automatically while there is a folder called "Ubuntu One" in your $HOME, thus delete that folder if you want to prevent Ubuntu One from autostart.

Then if you want, you can also restore the factory settings by deleting the following hidden folders from your $HOME

```
.local/share/ubuntuone/
.config/ubuntuone/
```

Please note that you don't have to delete `/etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop` file, in fact if you do so you might be into trouble when you want to use Ubuntu One again, however you can rebuilt it with:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop
```

by pasting the following and saving changes:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu One
Exec=/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=30
Icon=ubuntuone
Comment= 
NoDisplay=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=ubuntuone-client
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you include a simple script in your custom start up applications:

```
#!/bin/sh
u1sdtool -q
```

And the daemon should quit as soon as you log in.

Comment: I know about this solution :) I have quite a few scripts already starting up on log-in. I was looking for an "official" stop autostart.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the Ubuntu One dashboard, go under "Settings" tab and uncheck the "Connect automatically when computer starts". This way you can simply enable it after boot manually.

Hope it helps

Comment: that one is already disabled, and it's the same issue. I think this option only refers to the synchronisation, not to the start-up of the daemon.

Comment: You're posing a good question :) after [this bug fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/613219) it should not start. In fact it is not a service (bum or something else will not even see it - it is not a script in /etc/init.d but is a daemon in /usr/lib/ubuntuone-syncdaemon). Maybe you can see if it starts looking for it in 'ps aux | grep ubuntuone-*'. If so, you can update that bug and try to remove daemon from that folder in the meanwhile (but be careful, don't know how system will complain about this :))

Comment: I have only checked the outcome today. After installing Schweinsteiger's recommendation (bum), and indeed not seeing Ubuntu-One there (I did stop some other services though, from boinc) now I don't have Ubuntu one started. So I am not sure what happened...but U1 is no longer auto-started, and that's what I was aiming at. Thx all!

Answer (score 0):

I simply uninstalled UbuntuOne... Easy peasey.

Comment: :) I am waiting for a solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
```

**Reboot** , select the **Startup applications** from the `Top right Corner Menu`, there in list you will see Ubuntu One as option , Just Un-Check it to disable it Auto-restarting from next time.

Comment: As I have written in the question I no longer have the ubuntuone-launch.desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart/ folder. Furthermore there is no Ubuntu One in the Startup application. The problem is that the service is being started at startup